# Kendo UI Grid Not Populating With Data

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm attempting to use the Kendo UI Grid to populate data from a database. The application that I am creating is using Spring 3.2, Hibernate4, and Jackson Fasterxml. I know for a fact that my controller is returning JSON. I know this because when I hit the URL being called for the controller I get the following JSON response:

```
[{"applicationId":11,"applicationName":"LOS","url":"test.com","serverId":1,"serverName":"vmlosweb01","serverIp":"10.49.10.89","createdDate":1373644385213,"modifiedDate":null,"genericUserName":"lsdefault","genericPassword":"password1","orgId":null,"environmentId":1,"environmentName":"SANDBOX","createdDate":1373904291147,"modifiedDate":null,"databaseInfoId":1,"databaseName":"SANDBOX Database","ipAddress":"10.49.10.145","environmentId":1,"environmentName":"SANDBOX","createdDate":1373904291147,"modifiedDate":null,"createdDate":1373904415710,"modifiedDate":null,"createdDate":1374169441500,"modifiedDate":null}]
```

Here is my code:

appinfo.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            read: "/appinfo/findApplications",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10

});

dataSource.fetch(function(){
   var data = this.data();
    console.log(data.length);
});

$("#applicationsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 600,
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filterable: true,
    columns: [
        {field: "applicationName", title: "Application Name"},
        {field: "url", title: "URL"},
        {field: "serverId", title: "Server"},
        {field: "environmentId", title: "Environment"},
        {field: "databaseInfoId", title: "Database"},
        {field: "genericUserName", title: "Default Username"},
        {field: "genericPassword", title: "Default Password"}
    ]
});


});
```

ApplicationInformationController.java

```
package com.lps.appinfo.controller;


import com.lps.appinfo.model.*;
import com.lps.appinfo.service.ApplicationService;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import com.lps.appinfo.service.DatabaseInfoService;
import com.lps.appinfo.service.EnvironmentService;
import com.lps.appinfo.service.ServerService;


import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class ApplicationInformationController {

private static final Logger logger =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationInformationController.class);

@Autowired
private ApplicationService applicationService;
@Autowired
private EnvironmentService environmentService;
@Autowired
private ServerService serverService;
@Autowired
private DatabaseInfoService databaseInfoService;


@RequestMapping(value = "/findApplications", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public
@ResponseBody()
List<Application> findApplications() {
   /* MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter json = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    MediaType jsonMimeType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;*/


    applicationService = new ApplicationService();
    List<Application> applications = applicationService.getAll();

    // json.write(new Object(), jsonMimeType, new ServletServerHttpResponse());
    return applications;
}




}
```

When I debug the javascript via Chrome Debugger, the dataSource variable comes back with an arraysize of 0. So I'm not sure what's happening (or not happening).

Comment: Can you just try removing the dataSource.fetch(function(){
   var data = this.data();
    console.log(data.length);
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You have defined that the result is JSONP and as far as I can see from your response it is JSON.
2. The DataSource is incorrectly defined. In `transport` definition, there is a member called `read` but the `url` is provided as `url` and not as `read`.

So, it should be:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url     : "/appinfo/findApplications",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    pageSize : 10
});
```

Comment: OnaBai, great eye my friend! I need to pay closer attention to detail.